# How to deal with sorting for multiple Language in MongoDb asp.net core application using mongoDb C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I have a collection in which title can be in multiple language

example: If my Platform language is Spanish all the titles will be in Spanish. so how can I sort with Title

```
public class Collection
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: [Collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) has features to specify language specific rules (for example, in string comparison as it happens in sorting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two Ways to sort,

1. Mongo Linq
2. Fluent Aggregate Syntax

for both cases you have to use [AggregateOptions](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_AggregateOptions.htm) and Set [Collation.Local](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) to your desired local, you can toggle other flags to get your appropriate case sorting as well.

```
collation: {
   locale: <string>,
   caseLevel: <boolean>,
   caseFirst: <string>,
   strength: <int>,
   numericOrdering: <boolean>,
   alternate: <string>,
   maxVariable: <string>,
   backwards: <boolean>
}
```

**For MongoDb Linq**

```
var option = new AggregateOptions
                {
                    Collation = new Collation(searchParam.Local, false)
                };


        var list = collection.AsQueryable(option).OrderBy(x=>x.Title).
                ToListAsync(ct);
```

**For Fluent Aggregate Syntax**

```
 var option = new AggregateOptions
            {
                Collation = new Collation(searchParam.Local, false)
            };



  var result collection.Aggregate(option).Match(searchFilter).
                Sort(Builders<Collection>.Sort.Ascending(x=>x.Title).
                ToListAsync(ct);
```